# Populate Datatabase Table with timestamp using SQLPLUS inside a shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, ksh, sqlplus

I want to insert the last modified timestamp of a file in the database within a shell script. My script goes like this

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
date=date -r /raid/file/test.txt +%d" "%b" "%Y" "% r | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5;}'
echo ${date}
sqlplus USR/USR@PRODAR.AD.MANTO <<ENDOFSQL
INSERT INTO PROD_TABLE VALUES('$date');
exit
ENDOFSQL
```

I am wondering how to assign the last modified date of the file to a shell variable and use that inside sqlplus.Note that am looking for date in the format `05 May 2011 08:02:27 PM` The `$date` is showing null at the moment and is getting inserted into the table.
Would appreciate any recommendations around the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the output of the `date|awk` stuff in your `date` variable, you need to capture it:

```
date=$(date -r /raid/file/test.txt +%d" "%b" "%Y" "% r | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5;}')
```

Just that should do it but it has been a long time since I've used `ksh`. You don't need to access your `date` variable in `sqlplus`, you just need to access it in a string in your script.